# Random Forest Classifier: feature importance of prediction probability

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using sklearn RFC.

```
forest.fit(training_data, y_train)
probas_test = forest.predict_proba(test_data)
```

I wanted to know is there a way to find the contribution / importance of each features which lead to the prediction.

something like , but for an individual datapoint level.

```
   forest.feature_importances_
```

Comment: isn't `.features_importances_` giving back what you want ?

Comment: Thanks for responding @MMF. It returns for the complete trained tree, whereas i am looking these parameters for individual prediction of to be label'ed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways; check http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/ (and a Python package for that: https://github.com/andosa/treeinterpreter). There are also less direct options, e.g.

- https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05390 (implementation: https://github.com/sato9hara/defragTrees)
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05722 (implementation: https://github.com/IBCNServices/GENESIM)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks !